# How to disable swipe gesture recognizer from TabBar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using 11 Tab items. After 4 tab items it will show more menu, and when I click the 'more' button the remaining tab list will be shown - this is how it should work.

My problem is when I swipe from the left side of the screen this 'more' tab list is populating. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through gestures in the tab bar controller and disable the swipe

```
    for gesture in tabBarController.view.gestureRecognizers! {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            if (swipeGesture.direction == .Left) {
                swipeGesture.enabled = false
                print("disabled")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here `tabBarController` is valid instance of your tab bar controller.

You might have to do a bit of trial and error with `.Left` vs `.Right` and running this on only the controller's view or one of the subviews but this should definitely disable the gesture.

Also, although unlikely, lookout for multiple swipe gestures in same direction and if there are, make sure you disable only the relevant one.

In ObjC :

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in tabBarController.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if(((UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture).direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
            gesture.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes am using left side menu,using `SWRevealViewController ` i had implemented left swipe gesture,But when i swipe from the left end of the screen ,tab more list is showing

Comment: i guess this code is in `swift`,can you give code in `obj-c` ,thanks

Comment: Added ObjC code. However, you should seriously learn conversion between ObjC and Swift code and vice versa as most new answers will be in Swift while all the old answers have the ObjC code. Its quite easy too.

Comment: accepted your advice,i will try for that,thank u so much